# Flask-User auto login issue

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-login

I don't have much experience with Flask and Flask-User so bear with me. On my app, I want to implement these two features:

1. auto-login after registration
2. email verification (the user should be able to log in without verifying)

It seems to me that enabling these three options in my config should do the trick:

```
    USER_ENABLE_LOGIN_WITHOUT_CONFIRM_EMAIL = True,
    USER_ENABLE_CONFIRM_EMAIL=True,
    USER_AUTO_LOGIN_AFTER_REGISTER=True,
```

but with these settings on, auto-login doesn't work.
Later, I read [here](https://github.com/lingthio/Flask-User/issues/31) that setting `USER_ENABLE_CONFIRM_EMAIL=False` will fix the issue. So I tried these settings:

```
    USER_ENABLE_LOGIN_WITHOUT_CONFIRM_EMAIL = True,
    USER_ENABLE_CONFIRM_EMAIL=False,
    USER_AUTO_LOGIN_AFTER_REGISTER=True,
```

Now, auto-login DOES work but email confirmation does not. When I use `url_for('user.resend_confirm_email')`, I get this error:

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'user.resend_confirm_email'. Did you mean 'user.profile' instead?
```

I think there is a problem with my config settings. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post your views file. the one with view functions

Comment: The view functions are handled by the flask-user package. The views.py file  can be found here: https://github.com/lingthio/Flask-User/blob/master/flask_user/views.py. The method that handles this issue is resend_confirm_email

Comment: Have you really got those commas after `True` in your code or are these typos ?

Comment: Yes the commas are  intended

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to log the user in immediately after registration and also send the user a confirmation email? Unfortunately, after a lot of trial and error, I came to the conclusion that Flask-User does not support this particular registration flow. You can enable immediate login after registration, or user email confirmation, but not both.

However, you can enable automatic login after the user clicks the email confirmation with:

```
USER_AUTO_LOGIN_AFTER_CONFIRM = True
```

The user can be redirected to any URL after clicking the confirmation link with:

```
USER_AFTER_CONFIRM_ENDPOINT = 'insert_route'
```

This seems like a reasonable compromise to me, and is what I chose to go with in my app.